# Generating an iOS library with xcode 8

Tags: ios, static-libraries, linker-errors, xcode8, ios10

I want to create an iOS library to import in several projects.
I've tried to follow severa (many!) tutorial and guides, and also answers here without solve my problem.

I'm using xcode 8.1 (macOS sierra) and the steps to create the lib are the following:

- new->project->cocoa touch static library
- add all my sources into the project

Task already done:

- I've switched the flag "build active architecture only" to NO
- I've added to "other link flags" -static -objC

Now pushed cmd+B selecting a simulator as target

Go to Product->Select the .a->Show in finder

The library show that slice are:
'Architectures in the fat file: ./libPhoneNumber.a are: i386 x86_64'

The following steps show how I use the library:
- drag the .a into an existing project
- drag all the .h of the library into the existing project
- added the #import "libPhoneNumber.h" (the file exists)

Hit cmd+B using a simulator as target
I always obtain the following:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MYPhoneNumberUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

So, now the slice x86_64 obviously exist.

I'm going crazy, it seem that every guide simply don't works. 
Any other idea?

Thanks all

Comment: Do you have the path to your library in the build settings for your target?  (Library Search Paths)

Comment: My search path was ok. Thanks. I've found that the library works if the project is generated with new->project->cocoa touch static library, but if I create another type of project and THAN add a static library target, this target will not generate a valid library. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Digging into it I've found that the library works if the project is generated with new->project->cocoa touch static library, but if I create another type of project and THAN add a static library target, this target will not generate a valid library.